# Jest halts when parsing a decorator that returns another decorator

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I had been using a graphql decorator on my components (via react-apollo), and in an attempt to make my code more DRY, I decided to wrap the graphql function in another decorator like so:

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

export default function wrappedQuery(gqlDocument, numberOfItems) {
    return (component) => graphql(gqlDocument, {
        options: ...
        props: ...
    })(component)
}
```

Happily, this works in browser when I use it like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import wrappedQuery from './wrappedQuery'
import gqlDocument from './allPosts.graphql'

@wrappedQuery(gqlDocument, 10)
export default class BlogPostContainer extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

However, when I try to run tests with Jest, any test that imports this class returns an error pointed at the BlogPostContainer class declaration

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

    at App (src/index.js:10:31)
        at Object.<anonymous>(src/pages/BlogPage/containers/BlogPostContainer/index.js:13:53)
```

When I replace wrappedQuery with the identical graphql decorator, the test runs correctly. But as this query function is 15 lines long and subject to change between many classes, it's not ideal. Like I said, wrappedQuery is working in browser. Maybe this is a jsdom issue? I'm not well enough experienced to know if the problem is with Jest, or babel-jest, or jsdom, or something else...

```
// Works in browser and in Jest

@graphql(gqlDocument, {
    options: ...
    props: ...
}
export default class BlogPostContainer extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

I also attempted to use the function as you would without the transform-decorators plugin, but I get the same issue

```
// Works in browser but not in Jest

class BlogPostContainer extends React.Component {
    ...
}
export default wrappedQuery(gqlDocument, 10)(BlogPostContainer)
```

Here are my config files:

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [ 'js' ],
  moduleDirectories: [ 'node_modules' ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^src/': '<rootDir>/src'
  },
  transform: {
    '\\.(gql|graphql)$': 'jest-transform-graphql',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
  }
}

// .babelrc

{
  "presets": [
    [ "env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 2 versions"
        ]
      },
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "debug": true
    }],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

Comment: Oops, to answer my own question: my moduleNameMapper didn't work the way I thought it would. This alias fixes the issue: '^src/(.+)': '<rootDir>/src/$1'